# hot to create orbeon docker container?

Tags: orbeon

I would like to ask for some help to create a obeonforms docker container
Firstly I would like to describe the context in which I can reproduce the problem:

This is my simplest Dockerfile in which I download and configure orbeon for login:

[https://github.com/wagnermarques/Fedora-Dockerfiles/blob/master/orbeonforms/Dockerfile][1]

I made a 7min screencast on youtube to reproduce the problem visually. I will remove the video after https://youtu.be/5vE_rkmJV8U

I realize that either form runner and form builder seams to work when access orbeon from container ip but do not work when be accessed from docker mapped port

Below is some part of (the huge) log when form runner is accessed from docker mapped port

```
`https://pastebin.com/raw/53wXDpHm`
```

Can someone give some help, please?

Comment: A screencast that you say you are going to remove later is not helpful to the long term usefulness of this question. A question serves several purposes if it is well asked and answered. It solves the asker's problem, but it is also supposed to be useful for other people who find it while searching.

Comment: Hi Wagner, first, amongst others I'm regularly running Orbeon Forms in Docker, so rest assured that it can work just fine. I see you're running the `docker-run.sh` command. What does this do? I'm looking at your log, and the "interesting exception" might be the one at the beginning of the file, but we unfortunately can't see the beginning of that exception. Could you try to stop Tomcat, remove the `orbeon.log`, restart Tomcat, reproduce the error, and link to the whole `orbeon.log` you get?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your advice.  I think that If I not remove the screencast it can be util for the other users. In the future, I will try to reproduce the errors in own post.

Comment: docker-run.sh: https://github.com/wagnermarques/Fedora-Dockerfiles/blob/master/orbeonforms/docker-run.sh

Comment: I will reproduce the problem again and post entire orbeon.log as soon as I can.   Many thanks.

Comment: So sorry for delay. That is the entire log. I will keep the like alive for future reference. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fwmg_d9UZPX5ZUnk-rP2GvBJFN8XRW1Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So your container is internally listening on port `8080`, and you're mapping this to port `8070` of the host. Then I'd you recommend you try setting the `oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri` property to `http://localhost:8080/orbeon`. You can find more about this in the section about [URL rewriting](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/general#url-rewriting), and you'll let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @wagnermarques, did you get a chance trying to set `oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri`? If so, did that solve the issue you were seeing when accessing the Docker container from the host?